# Data Import in GA4 for dimensions

Tags: google-analytics-4

We are planning to use GA4 for our analytics use case for an eCommerce website. We have use cases to enrich our *view_item* event data and all other events with custom parameters which will then be used as dimension in the Analysis Hub. I have the following questions:

1. Size Limit - The data import csv file limit is 1GB in our use case we may have more than 10GB of data. Instead of uploading CSV file is there a way to enrich event data using BigQuery etc?
2. Custom Parameters - If I introduce a custom parameter during my enrichment process, can I use that as dimension in the Analysis Hub?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, BigQuery is a database, you can upload what you want, for example in a separate table and build an *ad hoc* query for what you are interested in obtaining.
2. Yes, you have to activate it in the GA4 interface.